# is this causing my app to stop?

Tags: android, xml

Cannot load settings from file (C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectName.idea\workspace.xml): Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. Please correct the file content.
is this problem causes my application to stop while running?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a SAXParserException. This means the file is a UTF-8/-16/-32 one with BOM.

> the byte order mark (BOM) is a Unicode character used to signal the endianness (byte order) of a text file or stream

[Solution](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html)